# Z3: convert Z3py expression to SMT-LIB2?

Tags: z3

Given an expression in Z3py, can I convert that to SMT-LIB2 language? (So I can feed this SMT-LIB2 expression to other SMT solvers that support SMT-LIB2)

If this is possible, please give one example.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use the C API `Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string`. Every function in the C API is available in Z3Py. This function was initially used to dump benchmarks in SMT 1.0 format, and it predates SMT 2.0. That is why it has some parameters that may seem unnecessary. Now, by default, it will display benchmarks in SMT 2.0 format. The output is **not** meant to be human readable. 
We can write the following Python function to make it more convenient to use:

```py
def toSMT2Benchmark(f, status="unknown", name="benchmark", logic=""):
  v = (Ast * 0)()
  return Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(f.ctx_ref(), name, logic, status, "", 0, v, f.as_ast())
```

Here is a small example using it (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/FFcT))

```py
a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
f = And(Or(a > If(b > 0, -b, b) + 1, a <= 0), b > 0)
print toSMT2Benchmark(f, logic="QF_LIA")
```

Comment: Could you tell me a similar API in Java to convert to SMTLIB2? Thanks.

Comment: What does the "v = (Ast * 0)()" mean?

Comment: Awesome! I'm getting a Z3 python segfault right now I have no clue how to debug. This should help a lot.