# Z3: convert Z3py expression to SMT-LIB2 from Solver object

Tags: z3

This question is very similar to: [Z3: convert Z3py expression to SMT-LIB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628279/z3-convert-z3py-expression-to-smt-lib2)

Is it possible to generate SMT-LIB2 output from Solver object ?

Answer (score 5):

The `Solver` class has method called `assertions()`. It returns all formulas asserted into the given solver. After we extract the assertions, we can use the same approach used in the previous question. Here is a quick and dirty modification to

```py
def toSMT2Benchmark(f, status="unknown", name="benchmark", logic=""):
  v = (Ast * 0)()
  if isinstance(f, Solver):
    a = f.assertions()
    if len(a) == 0:
      f = BoolVal(True)
    else:
      f = And(*a)
  return Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(f.ctx_ref(), name, logic, status, "", 0, v, f.as_ast())
```

Here is an example ([also available online at here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/6TkW))

```py
s = Solver()
print toSMT2Benchmark(s, logic="QF_LIA")
a, b = Ints('a b')
s.add(a > 1)
s.add(Or(a < 1, b < 2))
print toSMT2Benchmark(s, logic="QF_LIA")
```

**EDIT** We can use the following script to display the output in SMTLIB 1.x format (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/aY5X)). Note that SMTLIB 1.x is very limited, and several features are not supported. 
We also strongly encourage all users to move to SMTLIB 2.x.

```py
def toSMTBenchmark(f, status="unknown", name="benchmark", logic=""):
  v = (Ast * 0)()
  if isinstance(f, Solver):
    a = f.assertions()
    if len(a) == 0:
      f = BoolVal(True)
    else:
      f = And(*a)
  Z3_set_ast_print_mode(f.ctx_ref(), Z3_PRINT_SMTLIB_COMPLIANT)  # Set SMTLIB 1.x pretty print mode  
  r = Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(f.ctx_ref(), name, logic, status, "", 0, v, f.as_ast())
  Z3_set_ast_print_mode(f.ctx_ref(), Z3_PRINT_SMTLIB2_COMPLIANT) # Restore SMTLIB 2.x pretty print mode
  return r

s = Solver()
print toSMTBenchmark(s, logic="QF_LIA")
a, b = Ints('a b')
s.add(a > 1)
s.add(Or(a < 1, b < 2))
print toSMTBenchmark(s, logic="QF_LIA")
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: Is it possible to force z3 to return SMT-LIB 1.2 compatible encoding ?