# Implicit vs explicit existential quantification in SMT formulas

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Given the following code:

```
from z3 import *
a,b,c = BitVecs('a b c', 32)
f1 = Exists([a, b, c], And(a + b == c, a < b, c == 1337))
f2 = And(a + b == c, a < b, c == 1337)
prove(f1 == f2)
```

I would assume that z3 implicitly existential quantifies `a`, `b` and `c`, in this example. Why aren't the two formulas equal, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The way you formulated your query doesn't really check whether `f1` equals `f2`. Your query is essentially asking the solver to find `a, b, c` such that the following fails to hold:

```
      Exists([a, b, c], And(a + b == c, a < b, c == 1337))
              =          
      And(a + b == c, a < b, c == 1337))
```

And indeed, you can instantiate the outer `a`, `b`, and `c` such that the right hand-side is false; but the left hand side is an existential which is true; thus failing the equivalence you asked for.

It might be easier to see this with a simpler example; with just one boolean variable. You're essentially asking:

```
     x == (Exists [x], x)
```

You see that those `x`s are actually different, so we can rename the inner one to (say) `y`; we get:

```
      x == (Exist [y]. y)
```

Now, the right-hand-side is clearly true since there is a `y` that makes `(Exist [y]. y)` true. So, you are essentially asking the prover to establish that no matter what `x` you pick, it is true. Which is definitely not the case when you pick `x` to be false.

Indeed, you can ask Z3 to give you the formula it's trying to prove, and this is what it returns for your original query:

```
(set-info :status unknown)
(declare-fun c () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun b () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 32))
(assert
 (let (($x24 (exists ((a (_ BitVec 32)) 
                      (b (_ BitVec 32)) 
                      (c (_ BitVec 32)) )
      (and (= (bvadd a b) c) (bvslt a b) (= c (_ bv1337 32))))))
 (let (($x57 (= $x24 (and (= (bvadd a b) c) (bvslt a b) (= c (_ bv1337 32))))))
(and $x57))))
(check-sat)
```

Which is clearly satisfiable, by the above reasoning.

(See [Z3: convert Z3py expression to SMT-LIB2 from Solver object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775122/z3-convert-z3py-expression-to-smt-lib2-from-solver-object?lq=1) for the code that converts a z3-python query to smt-lib.)