# Python equivalent of 7th parameter of Z3_API Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string

Tags: python, z3

We are currently using z3 on python to check for feasibility of program traces. Based on the trace we create z3 formulas and assertions, our next approach is currently feeding these assertions to iZ3 and smtinterpol using SMT2 as intermedium language via Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string.

A small example:
    x = Int('x')
    y = Int('y')

```
s = Solver()

# Assertions
s.assert_and_track(x > y, 'p1')
s.assert_and_track(x == 0, 'p2')
s.assert_and_track(y > 0, 'p3')

a = s.assertions()
v = a[0].as_ast()
f = And(a[1], a[2])
print Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(a[0].ctx_ref(), "name", "QF_LIA", "unsat", "", 1, v, f.as_ast())
```

This produces the output

```
; name    
(set-info :status unsat)
(set-logic QF_LIA)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert
(> x y))
(assert
(let (($x12 (> y 0)))
(let (($x10 (= x 0)))
(and $x10 $x12))))
(check-sat)
```

Which is fine for feeding it to smtinterpol after some autocratically modifications:

```
; name
(set-info :status unsat)
(set-option :produce-proofs true)
(set-logic QF_LIA)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (!
(> x y) :named p1))
(assert (!
(let (($x12 (> y 0)))
(let (($x10 (= x 0)))
(and $x10 $x12))) :named p2))
(check-sat)
(get-interpolants p1 p2)
```

What we would like to have is a possibility to have in the smt2 output all the assertions without the hack to combine all 1:end assertions via AND to one equation. If tried to guess by the c-code docs ( capi.html#gaf93844a5964ad8dee609fac3470d86e4">http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group_capi.html#gaf93844a5964ad8dee609fac3470d86e4 ) the format of the 6th and 7th parameter, but I could get it worked giving him a list of assertions.

I tried for example:

```
print Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(a[0].ctx_ref(), "name", "QF_LIA", "unsat", "", 2, f.as_ast(), v)
```

But will run into

```
exception: access violation reading 0x00000004
```

Also just giving a list will not work:

```
print Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(a[0].ctx_ref(), "name", "QF_LIA", "unsat", "", 2, [a[0].as_ast(), a[1].as_ast()], a[2].as_ast())
```

Basicly, does someone know what is the python equivalent of __in_ecount(num_assumptions) Z3_ast const? Or is there another possibility to generate smt2 output from the list of assertions of a Solver?

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628279/z3-convert-z3py-expression-to-smt-lib2/14629021#14629021

Comment: Yeah this question i already knew, I derived from some of your toSMT2Benchmark* answers the Z3_benchmark* call. I just failed in finding out the array call in python but thanks to Nikolaj Bjorner it works know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, the Python API does not expose a python wrapper to the function that prints benchmarks. 
The C signature is:

```
/**
   \brief Convert the given benchmark into SMT-LIB formatted string.

   \conly \warning The result buffer is statically allocated by Z3. It will
   \conly be automatically deallocated when #Z3_del_context is invoked.
   \conly So, the buffer is invalidated in the next call to \c Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string.

   \param c - context.
   \param name - name of benchmark. The argument is optional.
   \param logic - the benchmark logic. 
   \param status - the status string (sat, unsat, or unknown)
   \param attributes - other attributes, such as source, difficulty or category.
   \param num_assumptions - number of assumptions.
   \param assumptions - auxiliary assumptions.
   \param formula - formula to be checked for consistency in conjunction with assumptions.

   def_API('Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string', STRING, (_in(CONTEXT), _in(STRING), _in(STRING), _in(STRING), _in(STRING), _in(UINT), _in_array(5, AST), _in(AST)))
*/
Z3_string Z3_API Z3_benchmark_to_smtlib_string(__in   Z3_context c, 
                                               __in Z3_string name,
                                               __in Z3_string logic,
                                               __in Z3_string status,
                                               __in Z3_string attributes,
                                               __in   unsigned num_assumptions,
                                               __in_ecount(num_assumptions) Z3_ast const assumptions[],
                                               __in   Z3_ast formula);
```

There are several examples of similar functions in z3.py that take arrays as arguments, and 
they use the same pattern where you give two arguments to the C functions: (1) the length of the
array (2) the actual array.
You should pass the length of the array and the unpickled array to the C function.
A variant of your example with this change is here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/rGEp

Comment: Thankyou, I brought together L. de Moura previous answers and yours at http://nirjen.privatepaste.com/ea4dd8159d maybe it will help others.