# Turning Off Z3py Print Truncation

Tags: python, printing, z3, z3py

I need to print an entire Z3 problem to debug it, but when I print it the output is truncated.

```
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
... Add many assertions to s ...
print(s)
```

How do I display everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
set_option(max_args=10000000, max_lines=1000000, max_depth=10000000, max_visited=1000000)
```

You might want to play with actual values to come up with something that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it not `s.set_option()`? Will this affect other programs that call z3?

Comment: The options apply to all z3py objects, not just `Solver`. (For instance, `Expr`, `Int`, ...) So, it does make sense it's not solver specific. Not sure what you mean by "will it affect other programs." If you mean if they'll see their own data-structures be printed differently: Then the answer is no. If you mean the z3py objects they hold will be printed differently, then the answer is yes. These settings apply to z3py objects only, regardless of who holds on to them.